# How to check if a Date is valid using conditional split SSIS Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am working actually on a dataset about customers complains.

The dataset is really dirty, because of that I want to split the data to different files. One of those files should contain data that has the wrong Date format. The only problem is that the ISDATE function doesn't work with the conditional split.

can someone tell me what function should I use to check a Date format using the conditional split?

I am using Visual Studio (shell) 2013

Thank you

Comment: I seem to get faster, better, and more answers when I [include just a little snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). probably because it is much easier for others to copy/paste/modify rather than writing an example from scratch, and programmers can more generally read the code to quickly see the problem regardless of what language in which the question was written. Most notably, it shows you have made some effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: What makes you think that ISDATE doesn't work with Conditional Split?

Answer (score 4):

The root problem with your question is that `ISDATE` does not exist within the SSIS Expression language.

Depending what "dirty" means to you, I would solve this problem with a Data Conversion Task acting as the Conditional Split. Route the failed conversion (Error) rows to one destination and the clean ones to another.

[image]

I start with the following query to simulate bad source data

```
SELECT '2015-02-28' As DirtyDate
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-02-29'
UNION ALL SELECT 'penguin'
```

The first is a valid date. The second suffers from an invalid range and the third is right out.

Within the Data Conversion Task, I generate a new column called CleanDate which just casts as a DT_DATE

I then simulate your destinations with Row Count transformations to capture how many good versus bad I had.

### Biml

If you have [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) or [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/BimlExpress) installed, the following snippet will create an SSIS package that looks like the above screenshot. Adjust the connection string as needed.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="tempdb" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2014;Provider=SQLNCLI11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_37465482">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Sample">
                    <Variables>
                        <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="RowCountGood">0</Variable>
                        <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="RowCountBad">0</Variable>
                    </Variables>
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="tempdb" Name="OLESRC Dirty Dates">
                            <DirectInput><![CDATA[SELECT '2015-02-28' As DirtyDate
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-02-29'
UNION ALL SELECT 'penguin'

]]>
                            </DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>

                        <DataConversion Name="DCT Filter DirtyDate">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column DataType="Date" SourceColumn="DirtyDate" TargetColumn="CleanDate" />
                            </Columns>
                            <ErrorHandling 
                                ErrorRowDisposition="RedirectRow" 
                                TruncationRowDisposition="IgnoreFailure"></ErrorHandling>
                        </DataConversion>

                        <RowCount VariableName="User.RowCountGood" Name="RC Good">

                        </RowCount>
                        <RowCount VariableName="User.RowCountBad" Name="RC Bad">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="DCT Filter DirtyDate.Error" />
                        </RowCount>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

### Caveat on "dirty" dates

Some dates that convert *just fine* in SQL Server won't convert in SSIS. For example, the ever popular yyyymmdd format can't be cast as is into a date within SSIS. e.g. 20150228 won't convert 2015-02-28 casts just fine within SSIS. `SELECT CAST('20150228' AS date) AS WorksFine` is a-ok in SQL Server.